# Weak closed in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $\omega$ be a bounded open subset in $R^5$ and $b$ be in $L^2(\omega)$. Put
$M = \{ u \in W^{1,3}(\omega): \int_\omega b.u^2= 1 \} $. Is $M$ weakly closed in $W_0^{1,3}(\omega)$ ?

Comment: At least, it is weakly sequentially closed: If $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,3}_0$, then Rellich-Kondrachov implies $u_n \to u $ in $L^4(\Omega)$. Thus, you can pass to the limit with $1 = \int b \, u^2$.

Comment: Can you explain, why does Rellich-Kondrachov imply $u_n→ u in L^4(Ω)$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because this is the assertion of Rellich-Kondrachov.